# What are the pros and cons of using interfaces in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, interface

I have used Delphi classes for a while now but never really got into using interfaces. I already have read a bit about them but want to learn more.

I would like to hear which pros and cons you have encountered when using interfaces in Delphi regarding coding, performance, maintainability, code clearness, layer separation and generally speaking any regard you can think of.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All I can think of for now:

Pros:

- Clear separation between interface and implementation
- Reduced unit dependencies
- Multiple inheritance
- Reference counting (if desired, can be disabled)

Cons:

- Class and interface references cannot be mixed (at least with reference counting)
- Getter and setter functions required for all properties
- Reference counting does not work with circular references
- Debugging difficulties (thanks to gabr and Warren for pointing that out)

Comment: Good list. I would add only on Cons - debugging interface problems (references not being decremented/being decremented too early - or in translation - memory not being released/memory being released too early) can be quite messy business.

Comment: Perhaps adding to the Cons the (little) performance penalty of using an interface in some cases. But in general, the Delphi native interfaces (not COM) implementation is very fast and optimized (as fast as a virtual method, plus some reference counting).

Comment: Debugging interfaces is rather difficult for me. Stepping into interface calls doesn't work cleanly for me on most versions of Delphi including XE.    Inspecting and understanding the application becomes more difficult, when interfaces are heavily used.   Fixing memory leaks has become nearly impossible for me in many heavily interfaced applications.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: I think performance penalty is so small (as you say yourself) that it would be misleading to add it here. I think in 99% of the cases this can just be ignored.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. @Smasher, @gabr and @Warren, could anyone of you please elaborate on the debugging difficulties? Are they inherent to interfaces or a Delphi interfaces implementation problem?

Comment: @Guillem I'm interested in this too since I've never come across debugging issues with interfaces. I wonder how I've managed to avoid the problems!!

Comment: @Smasher That's exactly what I wrote: (little) performance penalty. "In general, interfaces implementation is very fast". But there is some more hidden code inserted by the compiler.

Comment: How do you disable reference counting?

Comment: @Dangph just do not inherit from `TInterfacedObject` but implement the methods from `IInterface` yourself and always return -1 as the reference count. If you need more details, ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 12):

Adding to the answers few more advantages:

1. Use interfaces to represent the behavior and each implementation of a behavior will implement the interface.
2. API Publishing: Interfaces are great to use when publishing APIs. You can publishing an interface without giving out the actual implementation. So you are free to make internal structural changes without causing any problems to the clients.

Comment: How could component vendors live without interfaces ... But I have yet to see any exposing the API via interfaces.

Comment: @Mghie I was referring to components/libraries (mentioned in my first sentence). I know about Tools API, though it was redesigned several times and if memory serves, initially it was classes and functions, and not interfaces.

Comment: @Eugene: You mentioned components/libraries, but Bharat did not. An API to an application is an API all the same, and interfaces are perfect for it. A down vote to the answer seems entirely unfair.

Comment: @Eugene: Ofcourse but interfaces sets a standard for all of the classes that implement the interface. Only interfaces without classes do nothing

Comment: @mghie Interfaces don't work well for API publishing. If they were, they would be used widely in a component world. They are not. The main problem is that they are unmodifiable and when you have to create IMyInterface7 to add one method (and you can't change existing method declaration), that's bad design. We have practical negative experience with this design. So the suggestion to use interfaces for API publishing is far from good idea.

Comment: @Bharat this is a theory. Practically ActiveX has almost died due to limitations of this approach.

Comment: @Eugene: Then what about COM is it also dead? Infact i am not talking only about COM/Activex.

Comment: @Bharat ActiveX is just an example of how interface-based architecture took the technology to abyss.

Comment: @Eugene Most Delphi component vendors don't publish true APIs. They change the interface with each new release. That said, there's nothing about interfaces that implies a stable interface.

Comment: @David definition of "true API" please. Without definition there's nothing to discuss. As for abyss - did you work on component / library market? I guess no. I've been tracking it for 13 years, and saw the rise and fall of this technology.

Comment: @Eugene I mean an interface that comes with a promise that it will never be changed, only extended. Things like Win32 and COM fall into this category. "True API" is clearly a rubbish phrase. Do you know a better one? Stable perhaps?

Comment: @David The interface that promises that it will never change, is named "locked" or "sealed". Extension is also a change, and as I mentioned above, introducing a new interface to add a method or two (this happed in Windows too with Interface'd Shell API) leads to a mess in maintenance. The problem happens when you need to remove something due to the need to "block" use of certain method. You simply can't. And those limitations made use of ActiveX controls quite hard and didn't address DLL hell issue. As you can note, .NET didn't go Interface way.

Comment: @Eugene And isn't it lovely that there are so many different .net versions! You are right that all *solutions* only solve some of the problems and leave you to deal with others. I personally like being able to run 15 year old code on modern Windows, and vice versa.

Comment: @David For us it is lovely to have many .NET versions (it allowed us charge for upgrade when .NET 2.0 or 4.0 was released). I guess Microsoft thinks this way too. But for a user it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @Eugene How very cynical and grasping of you!! ;-) From a user's perspective it's annoying to have so many different versions of .net on your machine, installing new ones with different bits of software. It's less of an issue now that it's so prevalent but a few years ago I found it an irritation.

Comment: @David "Sad but true" (c) Metallica. I don't think average Joe even noticed just another version of .NET, because it was installed with service packs. When you as a developer look inside your system, you see a lot of unneeded stuff. But the user rarely does this or even cares about this.

Answer (score 12):

All I say is that interfaces WITHOUT reference counting are VERY HIGH on my wishlist for delphi!!!

--> The real use of interfaces is the declaration of an interface. Not the ability for reference counting!

Comment: Before anybody tells me about returning -1 in _AddRef / _Release: no that's not what I mean. I mean an interface where delphi doesn't even CALL those methods!

Comment: @Daniel, @Smasher mentioned in his answer that reference counting can be disabled (I guess by returning -1 in _AddRef / _Release). Why would not that be enough? Is there anything else to consider? Thanks

Comment: @Daniel: what's so bad about calling these methods? Do you really worry about the performance of one function call (one that is probably inlined by the compiler anyway)?

Comment: It's the pure fact that the methdos are called (behind your back) that matters. If you want to manage lifetime of your interfaced objects on your own (without ref-counting) this will bite you.

Comment: @Smasher: When I experimented with non ref-counted interfaces some time ago I always had problems with - IIRC - _IntfClear calls on interface variables referring to Free'd objects. However I can't create a small example showing that problem right now, so currently I can't see any problems here too. :-)

Comment: It's actually very simple what exactly is wrong with those method calls. The reason is the Interface cleanup that is made: Create an object, pass it as interface reference to a method, delete it again, leave the current method -> Access violation because _Release is called on the already destroyed object.

Answer (score 9):

There are some SUBTLE downsides to interfaces that I don't know if people consider when using them:

1. Debugging becomes more difficult.  I have seen a lot of strange difficulties stepping into interfaced method calls, in the debugger.
2. Interfaces in Delphi come with IUnknown semantics, if you like it or not, you'r stuck with reference counting being a supported interface.  And, thus, with any interfaces created in Delphi's world, you have to be sure you handle reference counting correctly, and if you don't, you'll end up with leaks.  When you want to avoid reference counting, your only choice is to override addref/decref and don't actually free anything, but this is not without its own problems.  I find that the more heavily interface-laden codebases have some of the hardest-to-find access violations, and memory leaks, and this is, I think because it is very difficult to combine the refcount semantics, and the default delphi semantics (owner frees objects, and nobody else does, and most objects live for the entire life of their parents.).
3. Badly-done implementations using Interfaces can contribute some nasty code-smells. For example,  Interfaces defined in the same unit that defines the initial concrete implementation of a class, add all the weight of interfaces, without really providing proper separation between the users of the interfaces and the implementors.  I know this isn't a problem with interfaces themselves, but more of a quibble with those who write interface-based code.  Please put your interface declarations in units that only have those interface declarations in them, and avoid unit-to-unit dependency hell caused by glomming your interface declarations into the same units as your implementor classes.

Comment: +1 for adding some downsides. One of the downsides I really dislike is that you cannot cast back from an interface reference to an object instance reference (which is inherent as the interface might be implemented by something like COM which is not based on Delphi TObject).

Comment: I believe you can write an "IS check" and if the incoming interface IS TMyImplementation, you can recover the TMyImplementation via as cast.

Comment: You can even do this with a hard cast as of Delphi 2010: http://wiert.me/2011/03/23/delphi-xe-introduced-safeintfasclass-to-cast-back-interface-to-class-via-oop-delphi-proxy-design-pattern-interface-problem-stack-overflow/ The as cast also works in Delphi 2010 and up: http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2009/08/21/38893

Comment: I guess that's safe since it's guarded by the is-check, and the as-check just repeats the is-check, so by my beloved DRY-principle, do not repeat yourself, the is, then hard cast pattern is ideal.

Answer (score 5):

I mostly use interfaces when I want objects with different ancestry to offer a common service. The best example I can think of from my own experience is an interface called `IClipboard`:

```
IClipboard = interface
  function CopyAvailable: Boolean;
  function PasteAvailable(const Value: string): Boolean;
  function CutAvailable: Boolean;
  function SelectAllAvailable: Boolean;
  procedure Copy;
  procedure Paste(const Value: string);
  procedure Cut;
  procedure SelectAll;
end;
```

I have a bunch of custom controls derived from standard VCL controls. They each implement this interface. When a clipboard operation reaches one of my forms it looks to see if the active control supports this interface and, if so, dispatches the appropriate method.

For a very simple interface you can do this with an `of object` event handler, but once it gets sufficiently complex an interface works well. In fact I think that is a very good analogue. Use an interface where you a single `of object` event won't fit the functionality.

Comment: This is a great technique, and I only wish that the VCL's TAction framework was interface-based. (If you don't want to customise all your controls you can use the Model-GUI-Mediator pattern instead and have the mediators implement the required interfaces.)

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces solves a certain kind of issues.  The primary function is to...  well, ...define interfaces.  To distinguish between definition and implementation.

When you want to specify or check if a class supports a set of methods - use interfaces.

You cannot do that in any other way.

(If all classes inherits from the same base class, then an abstract class will define the interface.  But when you are dealing with different class hierarchies, you need interfaces to define the methods thy have in common...)

Comment: Jorn, you can check if a class implements a method using RTTI, you can also call it using RTTI: interfaces are not the only way. They're the more elegant way.

Comment: @Cosmin wrong. RTTI was for a long time only available for published methods (not for public and below), so generalizing "you can" is not correct.

Comment: @Cosmin: An interface is much more of a contract though. You can use RTTI to check for methods and their parameters, but matches may be by pure chance. Note the "set of methods" in the answer. A class could for example implement more than one interface, each of which could contain a `GetCount()` method. They need not be the same method. No way to do that with RTTI.

Answer (score 4):

Extra note on 
Cons: Performance

I think many people are too blithely dismissing the performance penalty of interfaces. (Not that I don't like and use interfaces but you should be aware of what you are getting into).  Interfaces can be expensive not just for the _AddRef / _Release hit (even if you are just returning -1) but also that properties are REQUIRED to have a Get method.  In my experience, most properties in a class have direct access for the read accessor (e.g., propery Prop1: Integer read FProp1 write SetProp1).  Changing that direct, no penalty access to a function call can be significant hit on your speed (especially when you start adding 10s of property calls inside a loop.

For example, a simple loop using a class

```
for i := 0 to 99 do
begin
  j := (MyClass.Prop1 + MyClass.Prop2 + MyClass.Prop3) / MyClass.Prop4;
  MyClass.Update;
  // do something with j
end;
```

goes from 0 function calls to 400 function calls when the class becomes an interface.  Add more properties in that loop and it quickly gets worse.

The _AddRef / _Release penalty you can ameliorate with some tips (I am sure there are other tips.  This is off the top of my head):

- Use WITH or assign to a temp variable to only incur the penalty of one _AddRef / _Release per code block
- Always pass interfaces using *const* keyword into a function (otherwise, you get an extra _AddRef / _Release occurs every time that function is called.

Comment: The sample loop is a code smell suggesting responsibility for performing the calculation is in the wrong place. E.g. In this case replace the `j := ...` with `j := MyClass.CalculateJ;`. TIP: If profiling identifies repeated calls through an interface as causing a performance problem, consider refactoring to move responsibility to a more appropriate location.

Answer (score 1):

The only case when we *had* to use interfaces (besides COM/ActiveX stuff) was when we needed multiple inheritance and interfaces were the only way to get it. In several other cases when we attempted to use interfaces, we had various kinds of problems, mainly with reference counting (when the object was accessed both as a class instance and via interface).

So my advice would be to use them only when you know that you *need* them, not when you *think* that it can make your life easier in some aspect.

Update: As David reminded, with interfaces you get multiple inheritance of interfaces only, not of implementation. But that was fine for our needs.

Comment: Of course interfaces only get you multiple inheritance of interfaces and not multiple inheritance of implementations. This can sometimes mean that this technique gets messy.

Comment: That is correct.  Interfaces doesn't really give you multiple inheritance.

Comment: Eugene, "-1" your advice `use them only when you know that you need them, not when you think that it can make your life easier`. You surely had some problem with your implementation, and of course interfaces should be used if they make life easier. One can get into just about the same amount of trouble if they misuse or misunderstand plain objects.

Comment: @Cosmin how many Delphi projects did you develop in your life? Can we see some?

Comment: @Eugene, thanks for the vote of confidence: www.adicomsoft.ro - they're all Delphi, they're all mine. I can count 475 downloads over there, but that includes multiple versions of the same thing, going back about 10 years. I last worked with Delphi Interfaces... yesterday.

Comment: @Cosmin thank you for the link. The question was not about working (i.e. coding) but about experience with application (and, more importantly for this discussion, component/API) design.

Comment: +1 because, like Eugene, I only use interfaces if I really had to... that is almost never! I'll perhaps use them to have some garbage-collection feature for a logging mechanism I want to implement (i.e. instantiate an interface at the beginning of a method to log the entering, then let the interface mark the leaving of the method on release: just to use the hidden try..finally IntfClear() end block inserted by the compiler). In practice, I prefer using some well designed classes, and virtual methods. But that's a matter of taste. About performance, the Delphi implementation is very fast.

Comment: @Eugene That would be over the top, a down-vote makes the point succinctly without bothering mods and meta. Remember the incident with Jeroen?

Comment: @Eugene Agreed. I still think your comment to Cosmin comes across as being very rude, but perhaps you didn't mean it to sound so dismissive.

Comment: @David I don't see what exactly was rude. Cosmin's comments (not just the one above but overall) made me need to check, what kind of expertise he has in programming. As no information was present in his profile, I asked him about this. I can see your profile and see your answers (for other questions) with quickly and professionally written components and code snippets. As for Cosmin, I didn't see this, so I asked. The question we are discussing (use of interfaces in design of applications) requires certain experience with *design* besides coding, and this is what I said above.

Comment: @Eugene But you didn't clarify that as you have just done. Your original comment would, by many people, be interpreted as aggressive and dismissive. You could have used softer language to good effect. Anyway, you've clarified this now which is good.

Comment: @Eugene, information in anyone's profile is unverifiable any way, and it shouldn't really matter. I'm not about to discuss my person over here, and it sure looks like you attacked my person when you should have commented on my ideas. I'm sure you didn't mean it, but unfortunately that's how it came across.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond what others already listed, a big pro of interfaces is the ability of aggregating them.

I wrote a blog post on that topic a while ago which can be found here: http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=intf-aggregation (tl;dr: you can have multiple objects each implementing an interface and then assemble them into an aggregate which to the outside world looks like a single object implementing all these interfaces)

You might also want to have a look at the "Interface Fundamentals" and "Advanced Interface Usage and Patterns" posts linked there.